# SSL/TLS handshake fail rate

Tags: tls

I would like to know some numbers regarding to SSL/TLS handshake fail rate, i.e. what is the percentage of **(failed SSL/TLS handshake)**/(total SSL/TLS handshake) across the internet. By failure it means that all kinds of possible causes are all included.

I'm looking into related problems so I need data. Is there any sources that imply related statistics? I can't find them.

Comment: This is an unanswerable opnion-based question.  There is no data on what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**Hard to say.**

The most common cause for SSL/TLS handshake failure is an inability to agree upon a common protocol and cipher.  Because the protocol/cipher suite presented by the client is going to vary widely from client to client, and the suite supported by the server is going to vary widely from server to server, there's no way to do a real statistical analysis.

There are [real numbers available](https://jve.linuxwall.info/blog/index.php?post/TLS_Survey) for things like [supported protocols](http://blog.ivanristic.com/2011/09/ssl-survey-protocol-support.html) and [ciphers](https://www.trustworthyinternet.org/ssl-pulse/).  Those can be used to infer things like failure rates for older browsers (IE6, Java 6).  And then there's actual breakage like [Microsoft's ServerKeyExchange problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1253526/tls-serverkeyexchange-with-1024-dhe-may-encode-dh-y-as-127-bytes-breaking-internet-explorer-11) - quantifiable as the result of an intersection between two pieces of software, but **how often to they intersect in the real world?  Hard to say, and not measured**.

Comment: Thank you for your help and links. I've seen similar stats before and your links are useful as well. I also think profile failure rate like I described is difficult. I'm keep looking into it.  Thanks